# Jack Sparrow and The quest for the missing Compass . Part 1

Tags: logical-deduction, cipher, word-problem

***Hopefully this puzzle is not as easy as the last one.***

---

Jack Sparrow wakes up startled just when he was deep in slumber, after his night out with the "Ladies".
He checks his pocket and finds it empty. No Compass!!!
He springs up from the bed and notices some parchments at the corner of the bed. On top of the pile is a letter which says,

[image]

A panicked Jack, walks randomly across the small dingy room, and then tries to regain his senses. He looks through the pile
of parchment and finds a map showing the islands near "Death's Gate":

[image]

Jack thinks
***He must want me to go to the Death's Gate. Might be a trap. But do I have a choice. And even if I go there, where to find the compass.
It's not a trivial matter to look for a pin in those islands of haysack ... or haysack of islands. Not sure which one.***

He looks at another parchment,

[image]

> `3m1scTKxAeaHWIYSMmO0yAiTutiRtuWuzqLWktyAyX3r5zfCiUf3OXPvdHRRlKM5XXIqSAYnP5KE5fxb9R871VwhAOnTCsA3f8DElwmWKwyPd5g+G/MNG4PyOcRRCpCGSc6c/H5stdF4R7eu5WYgbg1BD0CTkAtD/IkLOuL/GFU=`

"***Does he take me for a fool, I am Captain Jack Sparrow.***"
He thought. He stared at it, turned it upside down, shook it as if the compass would fall out of it at any moment. No Luck.

He takes another parchment and sees something that looks like some kind of prose.

[image]

> Be wary of the seas
> and Be wary of the height
> What eagle Carries in it's Beak
> you will need it outright.
> You'll follow me fine,
> if you Clear your sight.
> Take the C's from the left
> and then B's from the right

He mutters,
"***I can certainly write better than that. The fine Ladies from the Port of Goron will tell you***".

He moves onto the next piece.

[image]

> Ser, you might be perplexed,
> and wonder where I went.
> But you will give up,
> once your will is spent.

"***Aha, so you are a poet my friend, though a pretty bad one I must add. Then you must lack courage and valor. I on the other hand, am Captain Jack Sparrow***".

Even though it's quite late, he goes downstairs to get a drink. A bottle of Rum and a warm fire, he takes a chair and goes deep in thought. Suddenly, he opens his eyes and runs outside
looking for Gibbs. He finds him near his ship having a Whisky.

Gibbs
***"What is it Jack"***

Jack hands him a piece of parchment and says,
"***Mr. Gibbs would you please read that aloud for me***"

Gibbs takes the piece of parchment and reads:
***Ser, you might be perplexed, and wonder where I went. But you will give up, once your will is spent"***

Jack thinks and reads from the other parchment:
***Be wary of the seas,

and Be wary of the height.

What eagle Carries in it's Beak

you will need it outright.

You'll follow me fine,

if you Clear your sight.

Take the C's from the left,

and then B's from the right.***

He smiles and adds
***Now go fetch me some rum

as we set sail tonight***

Gibbs continues where Jack left off:
***Do you also want me to get something,

to whip you Blue and White***

Jack Sparrow smiles
***Mr Gibbs, You don't understand. Someone stole the compass and I might just know how to get it back. We set sail now.***

***And Mr. Gibbs, bring KeyserSoze along, we need him to get to the compass***

Gibbs,
***Where we headed?***

Jack,
***We'll know by tomorrow.***

Next day, Jack wakes up late in the afternoon. Still wondering about the coded message. Something still didn't make sense. Wondering about all he had found, going through every parchment again and again. It happened while he was reading the letter. Specially the line ***Once is not enough***. He look at the coded message again and
***Aha, this is what I have to do.***

He picked up the map and held it towards the sun, then looked the message on the parchment he just decoded and yelled,
***"Mr. Gibbs, we are headed to ________"***

---

**Where is Jack headed?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mr. Gibbs, we are headed to

> The cave at the top of Oholu's Heart

Step 1:

> Gibbs takes the piece of parchment and reads:
>  Ser, you might be perplexed, and wonder where I went. But you will give up, once your will is spent

> Jack thinks and reads from the other parchment:
>  Be wary of the seas,
> and Be wary of the height.
> What eagle Carries in it's Beak
> you will need it outright.
> You'll follow me fine,
> if you Clear your sight.
> Take the C's from the left,
> and then B's from the right.

There are three Cs and four Bs in the second group of text.  Take the three characters from the left of the first text, "Ser", and the last four characters, "pent", yielding "Serpent".

Step 2:

Serpent is a form of encryption, I have learned.  I went here http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/decrypt/ and dropped in the text from the code

> 3m1scTKxAeaHWIYSMmO0yAiTutiRtuWuzqLWktyAyX3r5zfCiUf3OXPvdHRRlKM5XXIqSAYnP5KE5fxb9R871VwhAOnTCsA3f8DElwmWKwyPd5g+G/MNG4PyOcRRCpCGSc6c/H5stdF4R7eu5WYgbg1BD0CTkAtD/IkLOuL/GFU=

I used the key KeyzerSoze, Algorithm Serpent and mode CBC (thanks @George).  This yielded

> bB5pRsZ2axPhNZ/BkqAnsd7x/ixnRaFWGd+HcuM0c+f73QBBMt4EnWCWRpmHHoax654hWiQnB+bO0OH1czTiCUN+B2Y6grMHm3FEaMCz95EOqqGa6f7dLvHJfBGOgi3S

I put that code in where we had the previous code generated this

> https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=fG1dVZyGFMqCoAOc54HoCg#q=image+encryption+online+mozaiq

Some of that gibberish might have taken me to the right page, but it didn't direct me to the correct site.  Understanding Google though, I went here:

> http://mozaiq.org/decrypt

After saving this:

> [image: this image]

to my desktop I uploaded it.  I didn't have a password, and luckily I didn't need it. ;)

Comment: Perhaps the once is not enough line relates to triple DES encryption?

Comment: Well serpent is a form of encryption, but what mode?

Comment: @George What are my options? :) I've never heard of it.  Snakes and encryption seem to be likely companions though. ;)

Comment: things like Cipher Block Chaining etc. you'll also need a key (KeyserSoze?)

Comment: Leppy you son of a gun. You did it again. I take a not so insignificant amount to time to create a puzzle and youuuuu...+1. Expect a lot tough puzzle next time and not as many helpful clues...lets see how you fair then :)

Comment: @DippedBits Honestly, I just think that my mind works in a similar way as yours does.

Comment: @DippedBits Your puzzles are awesome.  You are right, rehashing all of the clues later in the description were a little obvious, but they didn't make solving the puzzle any easier for me.  I already had the "run it twice" portion and the Bs and Cs clue was probably the part that took the longest thinking time.  Keep up the awesome work!

Comment: The original plan was not to include the rehashing, and to convert B to Bee and C to sea. Also I didn't plan on including "Once is not enough part" or rephrasing it to not such an obvious phrase. But I thought that might be a bit much. Next time I won't second guess myself :)

Comment: @DippedBits I'm not certain I would have got it without some sort of clue to imply that Serpent needed to be run twice, but I agree, don't second guess yourself.  It is possible to edit a puzzle to make it easier, the opposite is not.